# Search for a string in a html with Python

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I have a question about how to search a particular html and get a part of it. The intention is to search for the string "string1" in a html that I get from `request.get`. An example of what I want to search in that HTML:

```
...
<td>

<b>UP</b> (1) -
<a href="http://192.168.0.1:1234/actuator/info" target="_blank">string1:6ebff63963bdba5477b50e1735ef81e1</a>

</td>
...
```

When searching for string1 to be able to save the IP and the port that accompanies it.

Thank you very much first of all!

Comment: Use `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: @MehrdadEP Thanks, its help me!